# Using Rails Serializers (active_model_serializers) to render key/value pairs based on incremental primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to format the serialized output from [the active_model_serializers gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) as key/value pairs.

By default, `ActiveModel::Serializer` renders an output like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "foo"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "bar"
  }
]
```

I'm looking to format the output like this:

```
{
  1: {
    "value": "foo"
  },
  2: {
    "value": "bar"
  }
}
```

Is this possible using active_model_serializers?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that active_model_serializer is following 1.0 of the format specified in [jsonapi.org/format](http://jsonapi.org/format/). I don't think you can do something like that, maybe you can try [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)

PS: Actually I have this problem, too. I can't figure it out by using active_model_serializer, If you have fixed this, please let me know.